# How can I make this barcode display properly

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, codeigniter, http-headers, barcode

I am using CodeIgniter with Zend Framework to create a barcode, which is done really straightforward:

```
$this->load->library('zend');
          $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');

            $txt = $_POST['Info'];
            // Only the text to draw is required
            $barcodeOptions = array('text' => $txt);

            // No required options
            $rendererOptions = array();

            // Draw the barcode in a new image,
            // send the headers and the image
            $data = Zend_Barcode::factory(
                'code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions
            )->render();
```

However the "Info" that is sent via Post is sent using an ajax function with jquery:

```
$('#barCode').click(function(){
            var datos = $("#concepto").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo site_url('articulos/barcode')?>",
                type: "POST",
                data: "Info=" + datos
            });
```

I know it works because I had a "success:" function on the ajax call however it returns gibberish:

> �PNG�PNG�PNG�PNG�PNG�PNG�PNG�PNG�PNG�PNG�PNG�PNG�PNG�PNG

I know this is the image but since the headers can't be rewitten it's being displayed like this. I already tried to open a new window but failed to do it that way too, anyone can suggest me a way to get the barcode image? in a new window preferably.

Answer (score 4):

You can try passing the address to the script generating the image into the source of an image tag e.g. `<img src="/path/to/image/script"/>` that is if you want to render the image within HTML. That is how I use my barcode. My code sample below using just Zend :

**Inside Controller/Action**

```
$barcodeOptions = array('text' => 'TEXT');

$rendererOptions = array('imageType'=>'gif');

Zend_Barcode::factory('code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions)->render();
```

**The View**

```
<img src="/path/to/the/controller/action/above"/>
```

Comment: should the path be since the index.php?? or just starting somewhere else?

Comment: or just starting somewhere else? Could we chat sometime so I can see where I am wrong?

Comment: Sorry been a lil busy. No problem we could chat sometime. But I do not understand your questions ^^

Comment: haha where can I chat with you?? do you have a twitter account to exchange info there?

Comment: Thanks so much for this example. No where else, including the manual, could I find the explanation that to show the barcode it must first be generated in a separate controller/action.  I was trying this for hours with no result until I found your answer.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to send the headers, you can use the draw method:

```
Zend_Barcode::factory('code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions)->draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the content-type header.  That is the only way for your browser to know how to display the data it receives.

You say that you cannot change the headers, why is this?  You should be able to use:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

Without that, you are probably getting a default content type of `text/plain` which is causing it to be displayed as text.

The browser just sees a stream of bits and rely on the `Content-Type` header to decide what to do with it.

Comment: maybe I am doing it wrong, where should I add the "header('Content-Type: image/png');" ??

Comment: I tried adding "contentType:'image/png'" to the ajax call but I get this error: Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at system/libraries/Exceptions.php:166)

Filename: Renderer/Image.php

Line Number: 343

Comment: You will get that error because headers need to be sent at the beginning of the response.  If anything after the headers has already been sent, you can't add more.  Try putting the `header` call as high up as you can.  If you have an extra line in the file or anything it can cause that problem.  The other way is to turn on output buffering, but that is more complicated.

Comment: Zend Barcode changes the header's Content-type as appropriate implicitly when you are rendering it. Doing it explicitly just duplicates it.